# MongoEngine : ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured

Tags: python, django, mongoengine

Getting the following error when executing the following line of command

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
session = Session.objects.get(pk=session_key)
```

Error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the   ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

Followed the following steps for the `settings.py` file http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/django.html

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE' : 'django.db.backends.dummy',
},
 }

SESSION_ENGINE = 'mongoengine.django.sessions'
```

Comment: Use, `from mongoengine.django.sessions import MongoSession` and then `session     = MongoSession.objects.get(pk=sessionkey)` should resolve the problem

Answer (score 3):

check this: http://petrkout.com/programming/setting-up-django-with-mongodb/

you lack

```
from mongoengine import connect
connect('employeedb', username='my_username', password='secret_password')
```

In your settings.py file.

Comment: Thanks for the link to my site ;).

Answer (score 0):

Check your models file.
While using mongoengine, you have to inherit the Documents class instead of the models.Model class.
Refer [this section](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/guide/defining-documents.html) of the mongoengine documentation for details.